# How to promote simple github library?

Tags: github

I started an open source project on github which solves one very specific problem which is encountered by event driven distributed systems. I position this project as a handy tool to solve common issue without sweat - just use my library.

But I faced difficulty to get everyone know about even existence of such a project.

So my question is:

- **Is there any common methods which addresses promotion of open source libraries and which can be done without money in relatively short term by one man - the developer itself?**

I found [similar question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/636/what-is-the-best-way-to-promote-an-open-source-product) but it was not specific to libraries.  I'm particularly keen to hear any stories of bringing a one-man library to the attention of developers.

Comment: I understand you don't like the answers to the linked question, but it looks to me as if you're asking the same question and simply specifying that you want different answers.  How does this question differ from the other, closed one?

Comment: @MadHattersupportsMonica in the closed one there was no specification on what kind of open source project should be promoted. It could be new database or streaming engine or something else epic, with which you can pitch on conferences or spend huge money on marketing campaigns. 


Therefore, information specifying project and available resources is needed. Which I provided in my question.

Comment: Fair enough.  I have edited the question so it specifically asks how to promote a **library**, rather than other forms of free software, and it doesn't ask for things that would make it off-topic (eg, lists of external resources).

Comment: @MadHattersupportsMonica thanks!

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau you may notice that the OP linked that in his/her question.

Comment: @MadHattersupportsMonica, I did notice and I still believe it is a duplicate. Hence my close vote.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau that is completely fair, and I will be interested to see if the community closes the question.

Comment: Libraries get used to fill a need. So the real question is if your library actually fills a need. There is always some other library that can be used to do XYZ; but will you support it, does it have bugs (of course it does, if you are honest), will it solve my problem faster or better than if I had just written some specific code myself? These are the sorts of things that you have to address in your library before even worrying about marketing.

Comment: @Brandin totally agree with your point. As you see I am not mentioning my library saying that it is cool and deserves to be promoted to well-known libraries. I am just planning ahead because this question is unknown to me.